# AngularJS ng-repeat over multiple tr

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to get the following code to work (data comes from an API):

```
...
<tbody ng-repeat="verbinding in data.connection" style="border-bottom:2px solid black;">

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{verbinding.departure.time  * 1000 | date:'HH:mm'}}</td>
        <td>{{verbinding.departure.platform}}</td>
        <td><a href="/liveboard/{{verbinding.departure.stationinfo.id}}">{{verbinding.departure.station}}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-if="verbinding.departure.vehicle == verbinding.arrival.vehicle">
        <td colspan = "5" style="text-align:center;">{{verbinding.departure.vehicle}}</td>
    </tr>
<span ng-if="verbinding.departure.vehicle != verbinding.arrival.vehicle" ng-repeat="via in verbinding.vias.via">
    <tr>
        <td>{{via.arrival.time * 1000 | date:'HH:mm'}}</td>
        <td>{{via.arrival.platform}}</td>
        <td>{{via.departure.time * 1000 | date:'HH:mm'}}</td>
        <td>{{via.departure.platform}}</td>
        <td><a href = "/liveboard/{{via.stationinfo.id}}">{{via.station}}</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan = "5">{{via.vehicle.id}}</td>
    </tr>
</span>
...
```

The code above doesn't work. The reason why I'm using the `span`is because I need two to include two `tr`s. The following does work:

```
...
<tr ng-if="verbinding.departure.vehicle != verbinding.arrival.vehicle" ng-repeat="via in verbinding.vias.via">
    <td>{{via.arrival.time * 1000 | date:'HH:mm'}}</td>
    <td>{{via.arrival.platform}}</td>
    <td>{{via.departure.time * 1000 | date:'HH:mm'}}</td>
    <td>{{via.departure.platform}}</td>
    <td><a href = "/liveboard/{{via.stationinfo.id}}">{{via.station}}</a></td>
</tr>
...
```

but then I only have one `tr`, and I need two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` might be what you're looking for.

From the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

> The ng-repeat-start directive works the same as ng-repeat, but will repeat all the HTML code (including the tag it's defined on) up to and including the ending HTML tag where ng-repeat-end is placed.

Perhaps something like this...

```
<tbody ng-repeat="verbinding in data.connection" style="border-bottom:2px solid black;">

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{verbinding.departure.time  * 1000 | date:'HH:mm'}}</td>
        <td>{{verbinding.departure.platform}}</td>
        <td><a href="/liveboard/{{verbinding.departure.stationinfo.id}}">{{verbinding.departure.station}}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-if="verbinding.departure.vehicle == verbinding.arrival.vehicle">
        <td colspan = "5" style="text-align:center;">{{verbinding.departure.vehicle}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="via in verbinding.vias.via">
        <td>{{via.arrival.time * 1000 | date:'HH:mm'}}</td>
        <td>{{via.arrival.platform}}</td>
        <td>{{via.departure.time * 1000 | date:'HH:mm'}}</td>
        <td>{{via.departure.platform}}</td>
        <td><a href = "/liveboard/{{via.stationinfo.id}}">{{via.station}}</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end>
        <td colspan = "5">{{via.vehicle.id}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```